# SOLR mm and phrase queries not working after upgrading from SOLR 4 to SOLR 6

Tags: solr

I'm working on testing a new SOLR 6 server (6.2.0), as we have been running 4.3.1 for some time, and it was time for an upgrade.

One thing I've noticed is that the mm (minMatch) term does not seem to work the way it used to (or it's being ignored), and phrase searches are not working properly either.

For example, searching for "tabletop scanning electron microscope" (including quotes) in our index should return two matching documents, but I get zero matches.

The search is set to use edismax.

Here's some of the debug output, in case this is helpful:

```
"responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 1,
"params": {
"mm": "4<-1 6<80%",
"q": "\"tabletop scanning electron microscope\"",
"qt": "dismaxsearch",
"indent": "on",
"pf": "headline^3.0 adtextintro^2.0 adtext^1.5",
"q.op": "OR",
"wt": "json",
"debugQuery": "true"
}
},
"response": {
"numFound": 0,
"start": 0,
"docs": []
},
"debug": {
"rawquerystring": "\"tabletop scanning electron microscope\"",
"querystring": "\"tabletop scanning electron microscope\"",
"parsedquery": "PhraseQuery(adtext:\"tabletop scan electron microscop\")",
"parsedquery_toString": "adtext:\"tabletop scan electron microscop\"",
"explain": {},
"QParser": "LuceneQParser",
```

The same search, but without the quotes, returns either far too many results when using q.op=OR, or zero results when using q.op=AND.  Again, it seems that mm is ignored when using OR.  When using AND, there should be two matches.

Any suggestions?  From what I've read so far, it seems there is a change in the way q.op works, but I have not been able to get things to work regardless of how I adjust this.

Please let me know if more details are required.

---

After more testing, I'm finding that the "qf" defined in my config is being ignored.  Or, possibly the entire searcher config is ignored.

Here's the config in my solrconfig.xml file:

```
    <requestHandler name="dismaxsearch" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <str name="defType">edismax</str>
   <float name="tie">0.01</float>
   <str name="qf">
      headline^3.0 manufacturer^1.0 model^1.0 adtextintro^2.0 adtext^1.5 companyname^0.2 clientnumber^20
   </str>
   <str name="bq">islvad:0^1.8</str>
   <!-- <str name="bf">recip(lvqualityrank,1,1000000,500)</str>-->
   <str name="bf">recip(lvqualityrankadjusted,1,5000000,50)</str>
   <!-- <str name="bf">product(lvqualityrank,-1)</str>-->
   <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   <str name="fl">*,score</str>
   <str name="rows">200</str>
   <str name="boost">recip(ms(NOW/HOUR,addate),3.16e-11,0.08,0.03)</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

This all worked in SOLR4, but possibly I've done something incorrect when migrating the config to SOLR6...

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: Here's an update on this.  If I specifically search against a single field, such as "headline", then it does find the match.  

headline:"Tabletop Scanning Electron Microscope"

But when I don't specify the field, it does not find the match. 
The phrase field (pf) param includes the headline field, so I'm not sure why specifically searching for the phrase in the headline field makes a difference...

Comment: Are you sure you have the "dismaxsearch" query handler defined in your new installation? That is not a standard query parse name in Solr, and your debug shows that it's using the standard LuceneQParser. This is probably not what you want. Try using just `dismax` or `edismax` to use the more modern version of the dismax parser.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh.  I've been experimenting with things, and found that it does seem to be ignoring at least part of the config.  Maybe it doesn't recognize the dismaxsearch searcher at all.  I can't post the config here, as there is not enough room. I'll see if I can edit the question above to include it...

Comment: Ok, I think I've figured out what's going on (thanks @MatsLindh for pointing me in the right direction).  The config wasn't being ignored... I was just calling it wrong.   

On our SOLR4 installation, calling /select  with qt=dismaxsearch  defined would work properly - the "dismaxsearch" requestHandler was being used.

On SOLR6, if I call /select, the qt=dismaxsearch is ignored.
I have to call /dismaxsearch  instead of  /select.  I also had to change the requestHandler name to "/dismaxsearch" instead of just "dismaxsearch".   

If there is a better way of doing this, I'd love to know.

Comment: @user3302110 A bit later, but there it is.. I brought some clarifications to my answer, I think you might prefer the first option but it will depend on your needs. I remember having the same issue a few years ago during an upgrade :) ! Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request dispatcher certainly has the param `handleSelect=true` (default and recommended for backward compatibility), in this case you need to ensure no request handler named "/select" is defined (solrconfig.xml), otherwise `/select` will actually handle the request regardless of the `qt` param.

> **handleSelect** is a legacy option that affects the behavior of requests such as /select?qt=XXX
>
> handleSelect="true" will cause the SolrDispatchFilter to process the request and dispatch the query to a handler specified by the "qt" param, **assuming "/select" isn't already registered**.

But if `handleSelect` is set to `false`, then the invoked request handler is determined by the request path (not `qt)`. In this case, a request like `http://.../select?q=...` is dispatched to `/select` handler.

So there is 2 options :

- With `handleSelect="true"`: just comment out `/select` handler definition and  use the `qt` param to specify wich request handler to use.
- With `handleSelect="false"`: specify the request handler in the request path (`.../dismaxsearch?q=...`). But this requires renaming your request handler to `"/dismaxsearch"`.

The first option is usually prefered and is maybe the most appropriate for those who want to be able to change request handler "on the fly", using a param is more instinctive and logical than changing path.

Comment: Thanks @EricLavault.  Sorry for my late reply on this - it got lost in the shuffle.  I had played around with handleSelect, but was unable to get that to make a difference, until I read your answer.  There was still a default /select requestHandler in the config, and that was causing the issue.