# Solr 7 Forcing q value

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7

I'm using the [Drupal ApacheSolr Multisite Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multisitesearch) which due to it's dependency [Apache Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) config currently only support Solr 5.x. I'm using Solr 7 and have update most of the config. I've got everything working except on /select. I believe this is because the query the module supplies (example shown below) features a "q" value which apparently causes it to fail. Is there a way in the solrconfig.xml to set q equal to "* . *" for all selects? I'd like to avoid code changes to the Drupal module itself if possible for deployment purposes.

Solar REST request example

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/drupal_multisite/select?start=0&rows=10&fq=%28hash%3A6qegyq%20OR%20access__all%3A0%29&fq=%28hash%3A6qegyq%29&spellcheck=true&q=test&fl=id%2Centity_id%2Centity_type%2Cbundle%2Cbundle_name%2Clabel%2Css_language%2Cis_comment_count%2Cds_created%2Cds_changed%2Cscore%2Cpath%2Curl%2Cis_uid%2Ctos_name%2Chash%2Csite&mm=1&pf=content%5E2.0&ps=15&hl=true&hl.fl=content&hl.snippets=3&hl.mergeContigious=true&f.content.hl.alternateField=teaser&f.content.hl.maxAlternateFieldLength=256&spellcheck.q=test&qf=content%5E40&qf=label%5E5.0&qf=tags_h1%5E5.0&qf=tags_h2_h3%5E3.0&qf=tags_h4_h5_h6%5E2.0&qf=tags_inline%5E1.0&qf=tos_content_extra%5E0.1&qf=tos_name%5E3.0&qf=ts_comments%5E20&wt=json&json.nl=map
```

solarconfig.xml example

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="df">text</str>
  <str name="q">*:*</str>
  <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: What is the actually error? Because what you are requesting (forcing 'q' field) does not really make sense. That's the field where your freeform query goes.

Comment: There is no discernible difference in how the `q` parameter is handled between Solr 5.x and Solr 7.x. Are you sure that is _actually_ your problem? `q` contains the actual query sent to Solr, so it'd we weird to always override the actual query..

Comment: Based on changing the REST query parameters, I figured that the query worked without q but not with. The issue ended up being with a handleSelect=true. I removed this other element and everything worked swimmingly. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to alter the query from your own drupal module, Apache Solr Search module exposes a hook for this (`hook_apachesolr_query_alter()`).

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_apachesolr_query_alter().
 * 
 * @param DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query
 * @see apachesolr.interface.inc
 */
function yourmodule_apachesolr_query_alter(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
  $query->replaceParam('q', '*:*');
}
```

That being said, if you *"got everything working except on /select"*, your issue could be related to your request dispatcher's `handleSelect` parameter, an option that affects the behavior of requests such as `/select?qt=XXX` (read [SOLR mm and phrase queries not working after upgrading from SOLR 4 to SOLR 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240555/solr-mm-and-phrase-queries-not-working-after-upgrading-from-solr-4-to-solr-6/40244565#40244565) if you don't know what I mean).

Comment: Your correct! the handleSelect was the problem. I removed this entry and it fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok writing some code (no in drupal module, but a standalone class/jar) then you can write a solr plugin (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins) and write a custom handler for "/select" (https://medium.com/@wkaichan/custom-request-handler-in-apache-solr-4f76521b031a) and in that handler override "q" parameter to "*.*" and call the original handler.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Yes, this would work but the other solution is technically correct.